# python exception handling

Tags: python

In the below python the message RSU is not supported on single node machine** is not getting printed. can anyone help please??

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys

class SWMException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print "inside exception"
        Exception.__init__(self, arg)

class RSUNotSupported(SWMException):
    def __init__(self):
        SWMException.__init__(self, "**RSU is not supported on single node machine**")

def isPrepActionNeeded():
    if 1==1:
        raise RSUNotSupported()
try:
    isPrepActionNeeded()
except:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last two lines to:

```
except Exception as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(1)
```

I use just `Exception` here to keep this the equivalent of a bare `except:`. You really should use `RSUNotSupported` so you don't hide other types of errors.

Comment: Exception.__init__(self, arg)
what is the arg argument in this init call for?? it doesnt  print the message

Comment: It's to make the message part of the exception, so you can print it yourself later if you want.

Answer (score 2):

It is not printed, because you're even not trying to print it :) Here:

```
try:
    isPrepActionNeeded()
except RSUNotSupported as e:
    print str(e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Exception.__init__(self, arg) the arg passed here. what is that for??

Comment: Well, you do have to keep the "**RSU..." message somewhere, right? Your exception inherits from Exception class, thus Exception.__init__(self, message) initializes the superclass and passes the argument (the message) to it. Now, your exception contains that message, and calling __str__() of an RSUNotSupported  class instance (or str( ) on that instance) returns the message.

Answer (score 1):

Because you handle the exception with your try/except clause.